# Adding search term to current query (Wordpress PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I've got this bit of code to do post-per-page filter to my woocommerce shop

```
function ps_selectbox() {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    ob_start();
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-ordering">';
    echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';   
    $orderby_options = array(
        '16' => '16 items per page',
        '32' => '32 items per page',
        '64' => '64 items per page'
    );
    foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
        echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
            
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ps_pre_get_products_query' );
function ps_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page ); 
        
    }
}
```

It will append "?perpage=$value" to the url and change number of items per page in the shop.
But when it comes to search result page, it will clear the current query and replace it with just "?perpage=$value"
EX: "https://aaa.com/?s=C21&post_type=product" to "https://aaa.com/?perpage=16"

If I manually change the url to be ""https://aaa.com/?s=C21&post_type=product&perpage=32" it works.
I tried add_query_arg( $args ) and a condition check but it doesn't seem to work.
EX:

```
function ps_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if (is_search()) {

    add_query_arg( $per_page );

    }
    elseif( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page ); 

    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Is there anyway I can keep this perpage dropdown feature in search result page?
Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: _“I tried add_query_arg( $args ) and a condition check but it doesn't seem to work”_ - completely wrong place to try and fix this to begin with. You are losing any existing GET parameters, because you are navigating to `?perpage=123` on the client side, by assigning that value as the new location, when the selected option changes. You need to make sure that any already existing GET parameters are kept/passed on, in _that_ place.

Comment: Hi @CBroe Thanks for your feedback. Do you mean instead of "$query->set()" I should use other functions to keep the existing GET parameters? I am new to all this so it would be awesome if you can show me the path. Cheers.

Comment: The URLs inside your option values, that you redirect to, need to contain all the necessary parameters, not just `perpage`.